# export a Google slide as an image via Google Slides Api or Drive api

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, google-slides-api

I am generating a google slide dynamically using a template ppt present in my drive. I need to convert this newly created ppt as an image and want to store this in another folder in the drive itself. I may have more than 1 slide in the presentation.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery

SCOPES = (
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations',
)
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'cred.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES) 

SLIDES = discovery.build('slides', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
DRIVE  = discovery.build('drive',  'v3', credentials=credentials)

TMPLFILE = 'title slide template' 

rsp = DRIVE.files().list(q="name='%s'" % TMPLFILE).execute().get('files')[0]
print(rsp)
DATA = {'name': 'Google Slides API template DEMO', 'parents': ['id_of_the_folder_for_storing_new_ppt']}
print('** Copying template %r as %r' % (rsp['name'], DATA['name']))
DECK_ID = DRIVE.files().copy(body=DATA, fileId=rsp['id']).execute().get('id')
print(DECK_ID)

print('** Replacing placeholder text')

reqs = [
    {'replaceAllText': {
        'containsText': {'text': '{{text}}'},
        'replaceText': final_til[0]
    }},
]

SLIDES.presentations().batchUpdate(body={'requests': reqs},
        presentationId=DECK_ID).execute()

### till this point I was creating a new ppt 
### now I need to save it as an image file

print('DONE')
```

Comment: **Exports a Google Doc to the requested MIME type and returns the exported content. Please note that the exported content is limited to 10MB.**   A slide is not a Google Doc are you sure export works with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The probably easiest way to implement your funcitonality is with [presentations.pages.getThumbnail](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/getThumbnail)

Use this method by specifying the

- `presentationId`
- `slidesId` of the slide you want to export
- `mimeType` for export - e.g. `PNG`
- `thumbnailSize` - in function of the desired quality for the image

The request will return you the `contentURL` of type
`https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=s1600"`
which you can use to either view the slide as an image in the browser or to create a file in your Drive from it.

**Sidenote:**

If you want to export the whole presentaiton rather than one slide, use [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) instead. However, this method only allows you to export the presentation only to PDF, not to PNG (at least not directly).